# how to inverse a mysql query?

Tags: mysql

Would anyone know how to inverse the following mysql query?

```
select * 
from test_results 
where TESTERID='3' 
  and TESTID IN (select TESTID 
                 from tests 
                 where TESTSREQUESTED > '0' 
                   AND TESTSREQUESTED > TESTSREQUESTEDTAKEN);
```

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean for "inverse"?

Comment: what do you mean by inverse of the query. please explain a little bit.

Comment: Are `testerid` and `TESTSREQUESTED` numeric columns? If yes you should not compare them to character literals. Use "real" numbers instead: `testerid = 3`,  `TESTSREQUESTED > 0`

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from test_results where not (TESTERID='3' and TESTID IN (select TESTID from tests where TESTSREQUESTED>'0' AND TESTSREQUESTED>TESTSREQUESTEDTAKEN))
```

Comment: Still no good. it is still returning testers with id 3. @melpomene

Comment: How is that not good? Your original query doesn't return *all* rows with id 3. My query returns the rest (because it's the inverse).

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
select
 * 
from test_results tr
INNER JOIN tests  on (tests.TESTID=tr.TESTID)

where tr.TESTERID!='3' 
OR (tests.TESTERID!='3' AND tests.TESTSREQUESTED<'0' AND TESTSREQUESTED<TESTSREQUESTEDTAKEN)
```

Comment: updated my query, please check now, I have used join, which will be fast and efficient than the sub queries having in clause

Comment: almost there. this portion is still not working. or (tests.TESTSREQUESTED<'0' AND TESTSREQUESTED<TESTSREQUESTEDTAKEN)

Comment: it is filtering testerid!=3 but it is showing all records without checking the tests table which should return only 3 results but it is returning all results except where testerid=3. thanks.

Comment: Hi Sashi, i don't want testers with testerid=3. your query is now giving me all testerid=3. When I change it to !=3, I get the same results as your original query.

Comment: What is the difference of result in my original query and your expected result?

Comment: the query from the tests table returns 3 results. Within these three results, test_results table has a record where testerid=3 which I don't want so I expect only 2 results and your query is giving me all results on test_results except where testerid=3.

Comment: Have updated the query, I think now, you will get, what you need

Comment: thanks Sashi. didn't work. I'll have to re-think the algo. thanks.

Comment: Give it a last thought, explain the content of the table and the expected result, by editing your question

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
select * from test_results where TESTERID!='3' and TESTID NOT IN (select TESTID from tests where TESTSREQUESTED>'0' AND TESTSREQUESTED>TESTSREQUESTEDTAKEN)
```

Comment: Time to refresh [De morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) (or re-read the question)